# My HTML page is showing the {% extends "/tasks/layout.html" % } statement in the page preview. I am using Django. How do I solve this problem?

Tags: python, django, backend, cs50, web-development-server

This is my *layout.html* file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Tasks</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% block  content  %}

    {%endblock%}
</body>
</html>
```

This is my *index.html* file:

```
{% extends "/tasks/layout.html" % }

{% block body%}
    <h1> VIEW BLOCK</h1>

   <ul>
        {% for task in tasks%}
            <li>{{task}}</li>
        {%endfor%}
    </ul>
    <a href="{% url 'tasks:add' %}">Add a new Task</a>

{%endblock%}
```

How do I remove this exteneng statement from my HTML page?

I want to remove the extnend from the HTML page.

Comment: The problem is in your Python code, which you have not showed us.  You are just returning the HTML instead of passing it through the Django template engine.

Comment: `{% block body%}` should be `{% block content %}`.

Comment: What are *"exteneng"* and *"extnend"*? Do you mean *"extends"*?

Answer (score 1):

its just a typo:

```
{% extends "/tasks/layout.html" % }
```

remove the blank between % and }:

```
{% extends "/tasks/layout.html" %}
```

all tags need to have this structure:

```
{% tag_name parameter %}
```

please check them all also for missing blanks